# How to calculate how many years passed since a given date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

This question was here for other languages, so let here be one for Ruby.

How do I calculate number of complete years that have passed from a given date?  As you probably have guessed, that's to calculate person's age automatically.  The closest one is `distance_of_time_in_words` Rails helper, so the following template

```
Jack is <%= distance_of_time_in_words (Time.now, Time.local(1950,03,22)) %> old.
```

yields

```
Jack is over 59 years old.
```

But I need more precise function that yields just number.  Is there one?

If there exists some kind of Ruby on Rails helper function for this, this is OK, although pure Ruby solution would be better.

**Edit: the gist of the question is that a non-approximate solution is needed.  At the 2<sup>nd</sup> of March Jack should be 59 years old and the next day he should be 60 years old.  Leap years and such should be taken into account.**

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Do you want age as people typically understand it, or are you looking for a precise measure of time elapsed? If the former, there is no need to worry about leap years and other complications. You simply need to compute a difference in years and reduce it if the person has not had a birthday yet this year. If the latter, you can convert seconds elapsed into years, as other answers have suggested.

```
def age_in_completed_years (bd, d)
    # Difference in years, less one if you have not had a birthday this year.
    a = d.year - bd.year
    a = a - 1 if (
         bd.month >  d.month or 
        (bd.month >= d.month and bd.day > d.day)
    )
    a
end

birthdate = Date.new(2000, 12, 15)
today     = Date.new(2009, 12, 14)

puts age_in_completed_years(birthdate, today)
```

Comment: It seems that not have you only answered the question, but also formulated the question in a better way :-)

Comment: +1, but what if I was born on, say Date.new(1980, 2, 29) ? ;-)

Comment: @Mike Bummer -- no birthday for you. Good point. Fixed the code.

Comment: Somehow you knew that the &*^$@ leap-year problem wasn't going away that quietly...

Comment: @Telemachus Indeed! Old Man Leap Year is a persistent bastard.

Comment: Would be nice if there was just a `Timespan` class! Question: shouldn't `bd.day > d.day` be `>=` instead? I consider myself a year older on my birthday, not the day after my birthday.

Comment: @JoshM. Good question: no, the code works he other way around. First it gives you credit for the year (via the simple difference between the years); then it deducts 1 if you **haven't** had your birthday yet. As written, the code prints 8, but if you change the `today` value to Dec 15, you'll get 9.

Answer (score 6):

```
require 'date'

def years_since(dt)
    delta = (Date.today - Date.parse(dt)) / 365
    delta.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I have a gem/plugin called [dotiw](http://github.com/radar/dotiw) that has a `distance_of_time_in_words_hash` that will return a hash like: `{ :years => 59, :months => 11, :days => 27 }`. From that you could work out if it's near a certain limit.

Answer (score 5):

I came up with the following, based on a similar reasoning as @FMc
First, compute the diff between today's year and birthday's year. Then, sum it to birthday and check the resulting date: if it's greater than today, decrease diff by 1.
To be used in Rails apps as it relies on `ActiveSupport`'s `years` method

```
def age(birthday, today)
  diff = today.year - birthday.year
  (birthday + diff.years > today ) ? (diff - 1) : diff
end
```

Comment: nice, this achieves the same as the accepted answer but simplier

Answer (score 4):

## An approach that handles leap years

Whenever you're calculating elapsed years since a date, you have to decide how to handle leap year. Here is my approach, which I think is very readable, and is able to take leap years in stride without using any "special case" logic.

```
def years_completed_since(start_date, end_date)

  if end_date < start_date
    raise ArgumentError.new(
      "End date supplied (#{end_date}) is before start date (#{start_date})"
    )
  end

  years_completed = end_date.year - start_date.year

  unless reached_anniversary_in_year_of(start_date, end_date)
    years_completed -= 1
  end

  years_completed
end

# No special logic required for leap day; its anniversary in a non-leap
# year is considered to have been reached on March 1.
def reached_anniversary_in_year_of(original_date, new_date)
  if new_date.month == original_date.month
    new_date.day >= original_date.day
  else
    new_date.month > original_date.month
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Same idea as FM but with a simplified if statement. Obviously, you could add a second argument instead of using current time.

```
def age(birthdate)
  now = DateTime.now
  age = now.year - birthdate.year
  age -= 1 if(now.yday < birthdate.yday)
  age
end
```

Comment: `yday` is a cool funciton, thanks.  Unfortunately, It will handle leap years differently, if the person is born later than in February.

Comment: agree with Pavel. `yday` isn't useful for comparing dates that span years because of leap years.

Answer (score 2):

withing http://github.com/radar/dotiw

```
Jack is <%= distance_of_time_in_words (Time.now, Time.local(1950,03,22)) %> old.
```

produce

```
Jack is 60 years old
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the ruby gem [adroit-age](https://github.com/raj-adroit/adroit-age)

It works for leap years also..

```
age = AdroitAge.find_age("23/01/1990")
```

Update

```
require 'adroit-age'

dob =  Date.new(1990,1,23)
or
dob = "23/01/1990".to_date

age = dob.find_age
#=> 23
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will always work, even for someone with a birthday near a leap day:

```
require 'date'

def calculate_age(start_date, end_date)
  end_date.year - start_date.year - ((end_date.month > start_date.month || (end_date.month == start_date.month && end_date.day >= start_date.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end

puts calculate_age( Date.strptime('03/02/1968', '%m/%d/%Y'), Date.strptime('03/02/2010', '%m/%d/%Y'))
```

The calculated age with this method in the example call above is 42, which is correct despite 1968 being a leap year and the birthday being near a leap day.

Plus, this way there is no need to create a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
def age_in_years(date)
  # Difference in years, less one if you have not had a birthday this year.
  today = Date.today
  age = today.year - date.year
  age = age - 1 if [date.day, date.month, today.year].join('/').to_date > Date.today
end
```

Answer (score 1):

`d2.year - d1.year - (d2.month > d1.month || (d2.month == d1.month && d2.day >= d1.day) ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please try to provide some explanation with your answers.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
def years_diff(from_time,to_time)
  (((to_time - from_time).abs)/ (365 * 24 * 60 * 60)).to_i
end

years_diff(Time.now,Time.local(1950,03,22)) #=> 59
years_diff(Time.now,Time.local(2009,03,22)) #=> 0
years_diff(Time.now,Time.local(2008,03,22)) #=> 1
```

Comment: This won't going to work when the current date is near birthday (leap years!), and for a person of more than 1460 years old it's going to yield ever increasing errors.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate number of Years and Months between two dates, I used this function

```
  def calculate_year_month(from_date, to_date)
    num_days = (from_date - to_date).to_i
    num_months = (num_days / 30) 
    num_years = (num_months / 12) 
    num_months = (num_months % 12) 
    return num_years.to_s + " year(s) and " + num_months.to_s + " month(s)" 
  end
```