# Find number of months between two Dates in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have two Ruby on Rails DateTime objects. How to find the number of months between them? (Keeping in mind they might belong to different years)

Comment: Was questioned and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5887756/rails-calculate-date-range-in-months

Comment: thanks for pointing it out. I searched but had not stumbled upon it.

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065320/in-rails-display-time-between-two-dates-in-english

Comment: I rather want the link in numbers. I got it done by the method referred by Massimiliano Peluso

Comment: Just i gave it for your reference.. Thanks Anyway..

Answer (score 201, accepted):

```
(date2.year * 12 + date2.month) - (date1.year * 12 + date1.month)
```

more info at http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/72120

Comment: This solution does not consider days. The number of months between 28/4/2000 and 1/5/2000 is not 1 month, but 0.

Comment: I need the one without considering days so this works for me. +1

Comment: Just another variant for this great answer: `(12 * (date2.year - date1.year) + date2.month - date1.month).abs if date1 && date2`

Comment: Its showing incorrect # of months if we try to fetch months between  2 years i.e. 2017-05-20 to 2018-05-20. The output shows 1 month.

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper It is showing correct months i.e 12

Comment: I have only one problem with this method, it completely ignores the day of the month, for example how many months are there between Feb 1st and March 30th of the same year? This would respond with 1, while it is almost 2 months.

Comment: Note: Add 1 (`+ 1`) to this result if you're looking for **"The number of calendar months that two dates span"**.

Answer (score 48):

A more accurate answer would consider days in the distance.

For example, if you consider that the month-distance from `28/4/2000` and `1/5/2000` is `0` rather than `1`, then you can use:

```
(date2.year - date1.year) * 12 + date2.month - date1.month - (date2.day >= date1.day ? 0 : 1)
```

Comment: e.g. for calculating the number of times someone has received his salary always being at the 22nd of the months

Answer (score 15):

Give a try to

```
((date2.to_time - date1.to_time)/1.month.second).to_i
```

Comment: `irb>Time.at("2014-10-01".to_time - "2014-12-01".to_time).month  
=> 10`

(I give up on formatting... can't figure it out)

Comment: Even if you use the Date object, @toby-joiner 's comment will still be correct. The reason is that <October> - <December> is -2 months, but Time.at(-2months).month gives the month equivalent of -2 (i.e. -2 % 12 #=> 10). Your suggested method will work if the two months follow one another and are less than a year apart, but it will fail if the two months are in reverse order (e.g. October - December) or if the two months are more than a year apart.

Comment: Time differences gives you a timestamp corresponding

Comment: if you use `date1 = '2016-02-01'.to_date` and `date2 = '2016-03-01'.to_date` the number of months is `0`. :(

Comment: Using `round(1).to_i` is more accurate.

Comment: I like the idea behind it, but it is incorrect if the datespan is becoming really long. In my example of `Date.new(2014, 10, 31), Date.new(1997, 4, 30)` I received 213 instead of 210 months. The reason for that is that `1.month.seconds` is the number of seconds in 30 days and not the average seconds in a month. Downvoting so that others stay bug-free.

Comment: this wont work if you choose a month that isn't 30 days

Comment: this method is not very accurate .

Comment: How has this gotten so many upvotes? It would be merely happenstance for it to produce an accurate number.

Answer (score 15):

Assuming both are dates:
`((date2 - date1).to_f / 365 * 12).round`
simple.

Comment: Very nice solution! Clean, simple, and even works across years – i.e. the range of months between February 2018 and December 2017.

Comment: Needs to take hours, minutes, and seconds into account 
`((date2 - date1).to_f / 60 / 60 / 24 / 365 * 12).round`

Comment: @scarver2 The number you get from your calculation is way off. All we are doing is taking days and converting them to months, it is not super accurate because it assumes 30.4167 days per month, but it very close and then it rounds anyways.

Answer (score 11):

You can rephrase the question as "how many 1st days is there between the beginnings of months of the dates", and then use functional-style data transformations:

```
(date1.beginning_of_month...date2.beginning_of_month).select { |date| date.day == 1 }.size
```

Comment: And to get back to the original question, you could sum the days (like you are doing with the first) and take the average of the sums.

Answer (score 4):

```
start_date = Date.today
end_date   = Date.today+90
months = (end_date.month+end_date.year*12) - (start_date.month+start_date.year*12)

//months = 3
```

Answer (score 3):

I needed the exact number of months (including decimals) between two dates and wrote the following method for it.

```
def months_difference(period_start, period_end)
  period_end = period_end + 1.day
  months = (period_end.year - period_start.year) * 12 + period_end.month - period_start.month - (period_end.day >= period_start.day ? 0 : 1)
  remains = period_end - (period_start + months.month)

  (months + remains/period_end.end_of_month.day).to_f.round(2)
end
```

If comparing let's say September 26th to September 26th (same day) I calculate it as 1 day. If you don't need that you can remove the first line in the method: `period_end = period_end + 1.day`

It passes the following specs:

```
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2017, 8, 1), Date.new(2017, 8, 31))).to eq 1.0
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2017, 8, 1), Date.new(2017, 8, 30))).to eq 0.97
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2017, 8, 1), Date.new(2017, 10, 31))).to eq 3.0
# Overlapping february (28 days) still counts Feb as a full month
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2017, 1, 1), Date.new(2017, 3, 31))).to eq 3.0
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2017, 2, 10), Date.new(2017, 3, 9))).to eq 1.0
# Leap year
expect(months_difference(Date.new(2016, 2, 1), Date.new(2016, 2, 29))).to eq 1.0
```

Comment: btw it relies on Rails' ActiveSupport

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that I found (built off a solution posted here already) is for if you want the result to include fractions of a month. For example the distance is `1.2 months`.

```
((date2.to_time - date1.to_time)/1.month.second).round(1) #Tenth of a month Ex: 1.2
((date2.to_time - date1.to_time)/1.month.second).round(2) #Hundreth, ex: 1.23 months
etc...
```

Comment: try raplacing round with floor if you whish to only show the months actually lapsed

Answer (score 2):

```
def difference_in_months(date1, date2)
  month_count = (date2.year == date1.year) ? (date2.month - date1.month) : (12 - date1.month + date2.month)
  month_count = (date2.year == date1.year) ? (month_count + 1) : (((date2.year - date1.year - 1 ) * 12) + (month_count + 1))
  month_count
end
```

Comment: It would be useful if you could elaborate on this?  Generally on SO answers include an explanation on what the code does and why it works as a solution

Answer (score 2):

Here's a brute forcing variant:

```
date1 = '2016-01-05'.to_date
date2 = '2017-02-27'.to_date
months = 0

months += 1 while (date2 << (count+1)) >= date1
puts months # => 13
```

`date2` must be always greater than `date1`

Answer (score 2):

Solution for any cases

```
(date1..date2).map { |date| date.strftime('%m.%Y') }.uniq.size
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this? I've found it pretty clean

```
((date2 - date1) / 1.month).round
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method. This will help to calculate number of whole months between two dates

```
def months_difference(date_time_start, date_time_end)
  curr_months = 0
  while (date_time_start + curr_months.months) < date_time_end
    curr_months += 1
  end
  curr_months -= 1 if (date_time_start + curr_months.months) > date_time_end
  curr_months.negative? ? 0 : curr_months
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the real months,then you must consider the **days**, the next code take in count this.

```rb
# get the real years between date, it consider the months and days
def years_between_dates(since_date, until_date)
  years = until_date.year - since_date.year
  if (until_date.month < since_date.month) ||
     (until_date.month == since_date.month && since_date.day > until_date.day)
    years -= 1
  end
  years
end

# Get the months between dates, it consider the days
def difference_between_dates_in_months(since_date, until_date)
  months = (years_between_dates(since_date, until_date) * 12)
  until_month = until_date.month
  since_month = since_date.month

  if until_month > since_month
    months += since_month - until_month
  elsif until_month < since_month
    months += 12 - since_month + until_month
  end

  months -= 1 if(since_date.day > until_date.day)

  months
end
```