# How to Loop through Months in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, loops

I need to loop through several months in a Ruby on Rails application. For each month, I need to find the first and last day of that given month. These dates are then used in a separate query to find events occurring during those dates and running calculations on them.

Initially, I tried something like:

```
(11.months.ago.to_date.month..Date.today.month).each do |m|
  start_date = '01-#{m}-#{Date.today.year}'.to_date.beginning_of_month
  end_date = '01-#{m}-#{Date.today.year}'.to_date.end_of_month
end
```

Of course, the year isn't updated in this case in the event that 11 months ago involves going back to the previous year. And, I don't think this type of for/each loop works. I also tried mapping the numbers to an array and using the same method, but received an error.

What's the best way to accomplish something like this?

Comment: Are you expecting arbitrary start/end dates?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, count the number of months between two dates (*courtesy of [Massimiliano Peluso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9428676/1153362)*):

```
start_date = 13.months.ago.to_date
# => Wed, 16 Nov 2011

end_date = Date.today
# => Sun, 16 Dec 2012

number_of_months = (end_date.year*12+end_date.month)-(start_date.year*12+start_date.month)
# => 13
```

Then from the start month, counting each month thereafter, find the first/last dates and append to an accumulator array.

```
dates = number_of_months.times.each_with_object([]) do |count, array|
  array << [start_date.beginning_of_month + count.months,
            start_date.end_of_month + count.months]
end
# => ...
```

Now `dates` will contain an array with nested `Date` pairs corresponding to the first and last date of each month. This `dates` array will be easy to iterate for processing.

```
dates
# => [[Tue, 01 Nov 2011, Wed, 30 Nov 2011], [Thu, 01 Dec 2011, Fri, 30 Dec 2011], ...

dates[0].first
# => Tue, 01 Nov 2011

dates[0].last
# => Wed, 30 Nov 2011

dates[0].last.class
# => Date
```

This is tested and working in Rails 3.2.5/Ruby 1.9.3p194

Comment: Thanks- I thought this was the best explanation and was the cleanest way to implement in my case (also adjusted for years).

Comment: `Fri, 30 Dec 2011` is not the last day of December

Comment: @mikdiet is correct here. If the start date is not in a 31 day month, this method will not return the last day of the month with 31 days.

Answer (score 17):

Here's one way to do it:

```
number_of_months = 0..11
number_of_months.to_a.reverse.each do |month_offset|
  start_date = month_offset.months.ago.beginning_of_month
  end_date = month_offset.months.ago.end_of_month
  puts "Start date : #{start_date} End date : #{end_date}"
end
```

=>

```
Start date : 2012-01-01 00:00:00 -0700 End date : 2012-01-31 23:59:59 -0700
Start date : 2012-02-01 00:00:00 -0700 End date : 2012-02-29 23:59:59 -0700
Start date : 2012-03-01 00:00:00 -0700 End date : 2012-03-31 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-04-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-04-30 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-05-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-05-31 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-06-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-06-30 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-07-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-07-31 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-08-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-08-31 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-09-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-09-30 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-10-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-10-31 23:59:59 -0600
Start date : 2012-11-01 00:00:00 -0600 End date : 2012-11-30 23:59:59 -0700
Start date : 2012-12-01 00:00:00 -0700 End date : 2012-12-31 23:59:59 -0700
```

Comment: Yes;this is with `rails 3.0.10` on `ruby 1.8.7`

Answer (score 12):

```
(start_date..end_date).select{|date| date.day == 1}.map{|date| [date.beginning_of_month, date.end_of_month]}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
time_start = 13.months.ago
time_end = 0.seconds.ago
time = time_start
while time < time_end
  puts("m:#{time.month} y:#{time.year}")
  time = time.advance(months: 1)
end
```

Comment: Well the ``Date.advance`` method doesn't seem to exist anymore. You can use ``Date.next_month`` or ``mydate >> 1`` to advance 1 month in time. See http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-next_month

Comment: Or `time += 1.month`

Answer (score 0):

start and end of next 12 months from (including) some_date:

```
(0..11).map do |m| 
  start_date = some_date.at_beginning_of_month + m.month
  end_date = start_date.at_end_of_month
end
```