# Rendering amount of months something was done in html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering if it's possible to get amount of months in rails from response.
If my data contains `published.at: '2020-12-31 08:00:00 UTC'`.
How can I render in my html `Published: 3 months ago` instead of displaying the entire date?
Now I display it as `<%= item.published_at %>`

Comment: Does this have a decent answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428605/find-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @BenStephens need this to be done in html only

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, it's in ERB isn't it? If yes, you should be able to put ruby code in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [time_ago_in_words](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.0/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words)

```
Published <%= time_ago_in_words(item.published_at) %> ago
```