# Calculate how many n.months between two dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I want to calculate the distance between two dates by month:

#### Q: start_date + n.months >= end_dates, what is the variable n?

```rb
start_date = Date.parse('2021-01-31')
end_date = Date.parse('2021-02-28')

## start_date + 1.months = 2021-02-28
## The answer 1 month, which is more clearable for human using
## Don't want to find the answer like 28 days or 0.93 month. (30 day a month)
```

First I tried to let each month is 30.days, but the answer will have some bias on some special dates. Each month's date is different, and the date on `End of Feb month` is always the problem.

Then I tried to install gems like `date_diff`, `time_difference`..., but no methods can do this, most of the output is 28 days but not 1 month.

For simple way, I can easily do the iterated loop to find the `n`, like:

```rb
start_date = Date.parse('2021-01-31')
end_date = Date.parse('2021-02-28')

def calc_diff(start_date, end_date)
  n = 0
  while start_date + n.months < end_date
     n += 1
  end
  n
end
```

Is there any better way to find the `n` months between two dates instead, but not use a loop?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find number of months between two Dates in Ruby on Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428605/find-number-of-months-between-two-dates-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari Nope, Most of the answers set the year's day at 365 and 30 days a month, or not handle the day's column (only handle date's month and year).  It will cause the problem at some end of the month (especially Feb.).

Comment: when i think again your question, i see your target is `more clearable for human using` that mean from 31-1 to 29-2 is 1 month and so i wonder whether 29-2 to 31-3 is also just 1 month (human point of view) or 2 months ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @Cary's and @Lam's answer.

Here is my answer to find the `n month`.

```rb
# try to find the minimum n month between start_date and target_date
def calc_diff(start_date, target_date)
  months_diff = (target_date.year * 12 + target_date.month) - (start_date.year * 12 + start_date.month)

  ## need to check the end of month because some special case
  ## start date: 2020-01-31 ; end date 2020-06-30
  ## the minimum n month must be 5
  ## another special case of Feb must consider (test case 15)

  if start_date.day > target_date.day && !((start_date == start_date.end_of_month || target_date.month == 2) && (target_date == target_date.end_of_month))
    months_diff = months_diff - 1
  end
  puts months_diff # it will show the minimum whole n month

  # the target_date will between inside
  # (start_date + months_diff.months) <= target_date < (start_date + (months_diff + 1).months) 
  (start_date + months_diff.months)..(start_date + (months_diff + 1).months) 
end
```

The Test Cases:

```rb
## test case 1
## 6/15 - 7/15  => n = 5
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-15'), Date.parse('2020-06-19'))

## test case 2
## 7/15 - 8/15  => n = 6
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-15'), Date.parse('2020-07-15')) 

## test case 3
## 5/15 - 6/15  => n = 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-15'), Date.parse('2020-06-01')) 

## test case 4 (special case)
## 6/30 - 7/31  => n = 5
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-31'), Date.parse('2020-06-30'))

## test case 5
## 7/30 - 8/30  => n = 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-04-30'), Date.parse('2020-07-31'))

## test case 6
## 6/30 - 7/30  => n = 2
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-04-30'), Date.parse('2020-06-30'))  

## test case 7
## 5/31 - 6/30  => n = 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-31'), Date.parse('2020-05-31'))

## test case 8
## 2/29 - 3/31  => n = 1
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-31'), Date.parse('2020-02-29'))

## test case 9
## 6/29 - 7/29  => n = 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-02-29'), Date.parse('2020-06-30'))

## test case 10
## 7/29 - 8/29  => n = 5
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-02-29'), Date.parse('2020-07-31'))

## test case 11
## 1/31 - 2/29  => n = 0
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-31'), Date.parse('2020-02-28'))

## test case 12
## 2/29 - 3/31  => n = 1
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-31'), Date.parse('2020-03-01'))

## test case 13
## 1/17 - 2/17  => n = 0
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-17'), Date.parse('2020-01-17'))

## test case 14
## 1/17 - 2/17  => n = 0
calc_diff(Date.parse('2020-01-17'), Date.parse('2020-01-18'))

## test case 15 (special case)
## 1/30 - 2/29  => n = 1
calc_diff(Date.parse('2019-12-30'), Date.parse('2020-02-28'))

## test case 16
## 2/29 - 3/30  => n = 2
calc_diff(Date.parse('2019-12-30'), Date.parse('2020-02-29'))
```

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of the question is consistent with the examples below. I have computed the difference between `Date` objects `date1` and `date2`, where `date2 >= date1`.

```
require 'date'
```

```
def months_between(date1, date2)
  12*(date2.yr - date1.yr) + date2.mon - date1.mon + date2.day > date1.day ? 1 : 0
end
```

```
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2020, 3, 21) #=> 2
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2020, 3, 22) #=> 2 
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2020, 3, 23) #=> 3
```

```
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2021, 3, 21) #=> 14
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2021, 3, 22) #=> 14
months_between Date.new(2020, 1, 22), Date.new(2021, 3, 23) #=> 15
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
# find minimum n so that `start_date + n.months >= end_dates`
def calc_diff(start_date, end_date)
 diff = (end_date.yday - start_date.yday) / 30
 return diff if start_date + diff.months >= end_date
 diff + 1
end

calc_diff(Date.parse('2021-01-31'), Date.parse('2021-02-28')) # 1
calc_diff(Date.parse('2021-01-31'), Date.parse('2021-04-30')) # 3
calc_diff(Date.parse('2021-01-31'), Date.parse('2021-05-31')) # 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2021-02-01'), Date.parse('2021-06-01')) # 4
calc_diff(Date.parse('2021-02-01'), Date.parse('2021-06-02')) # 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try to add another condition to control if the start date and end date is a different year.

Comment: nice, i missed that case.