# Ruby Converting Datestamp to Years old in Ruby

Tags: ruby, datestamp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate how many years passed since a given date in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904097/how-to-calculate-how-many-years-passed-since-a-given-date-in-ruby)

I am trying to convert a datestamp taken from the database into value indicating how many years old a person is. I am sure this easy, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: It *ALWAYS* helps to add some source code showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the datestamp is being retrieved as a DateTime value:

```
require 'date'

birth_date = DateTime.parse('1970-01-01 1:35 AM')
time_now = DateTime.now

(time_now - birth_date).to_i / 365 # => 41
(time_now - birth_date).to_f / 365 # => 41.38907504054664
```

`birth_date` is a mock value for what you should be retrieving from your database. The first value is years, the second is fractional years.

Alternately, you can do it this way:

```
years = time_now.year - birth_date.year
years -= 1 if (birth_date.month > time_now.month)
years # => 41
```

This adjusts in case the person hasn't had their birthday yet. For instance, tweaking the birthday:

```
birth_date = DateTime.parse('1970-12-31 11:59 PM')
years = time_now.year - birth_date.year
years -= 1 if (birth_date.month > time_now.month)
years # => 40
```

Comment: It doesn't bother with leap years. It's just a quick and dirty value.