# Elegant way to calculate number of years between two dates in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I currently have this less-than-ideal solution:

```
  def years_between_dates(date_from, date_to)
    ((date_to.to_time - date_from.to_time) / 1.year.seconds).floor
  end
```

The calculation doesn't have to be exact (w/ leap years etc), but does need to be fairly accurate and take into account months. 3.8 years should return 3 years, hence the `floor`.

I am converting `to_time` to account for both `Date`, `Time`, and `DateTime`.

I can't help but think there is a more succinct way of doing the above.

Comment: To start you could get rid of the `.to_i` and `.to_f` calls. They are unnecessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904097/how-to-calculate-how-many-years-passed-since-a-given-date-in-ruby

Comment: @ptd why do I not need `to_f`? It is my understanding that division of two integers will return a rounded up number?

Comment: **If you're going to downvote, at least post a comment with why so people can learn.**

Comment: @Damien Roche Subtracting two times will result in a float. You are getting an int because you are calling `.to_i` on the times.

Comment: @ptd I see. That makes the solution much cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

Seems like yours is in fact the most elegant way.

Even in the definition of `distance_of_time_in_words` rails has:

```
distance_in_minutes = ((to_time - from_time) / 60.0).round
distance_in_seconds = (to_time - from_time).round
```

[Reference](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2c97fbf6503c9199f3fe5ed06222e7226dc6fcd9/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L101)

A little better version could be:

```
def years_between_dates(date_from, date_to)
  ((date_to - date_from) / 365).floor
end
```

Comment: oh sorry. yeah makes sense

Comment: What if there are more than 365 leap years between date_from and date_to?

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled across this looking for something else...

Am I crazy? Can't you just do:

```
def years_between_dates(date_from, date_to)
  date_to.year - date_from.year
end
```

or if you needed it to say "years" afterwards:

```
def years_between_dates(date_from, date_to)
  return "#{date_to.year - date_from.year} years"
end
```

I see that **Piioo** is right, here is a revised version. But it also doesn't compensate for leap years, which would require something more elaborate. I wouldn't use this for longer periods where accuracy is key.

```
def years_between_dates(date_from, date_to)
  years = (date_to - date_from).to_i / 365
  return "#{years} years"
end
```

Comment: This one is better~

Comment: This guy is a true Rubyist.

Comment: But that's not the same as in the question.

It does not consider the months or days of the year. Between 1979-10-20 and 2020-10-19 are 40 years. But on 2020-10-20 its 41. 

In your calculation the whole year 2020 is 41 years.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the real years between two dates, you have to consider the months and days, for example if you want to get the dates between 2010-10-01 to 2021-09-09 , the real years must be 10 years. Then you can use the next function:

```rb
  def years_between_dates(since_date, until_date)
    years = until_date.year - since_date.year
    if (until_date.month < since_date.month) ||
       (until_date.month == since_date.month && until_date.day < since_date.day)
      years -= 1
    end
    years
  end
```

Comment: can this condition be simplified to `until_date.month <= since_date.month && until_date.day < since_date.day`?

Answer (score 1):

Simple as:

```
((Time.now-1.year.ago)/1.year).abs
```